# Contact Switch Sparking

Tags: switching, spark

Wanting to know if the contacts in switch sw1 spark (see circuit diagram below), I did a simple test and found that there are no sparks even with high amperage.
I am unable to explain why this is so? Also, would it make a difference if the switch were to toggle at frequency as there will be rapid current reversal in wire w1, notwithstanding that I appreciate the fact that there is not inductive load?
I appreciate that wire w1 sees no potential difference between its ends.  I am intrigued, however, by the fact that as I vary the effective conductor area either side of sw1, (therefore changing the resistance somewhat) there seems to be no current flow in w1. I have difficulty in grasping things in a visual analogue.
Many thanks.
[image]

Answer (score 0):

> Wanting to know if the contacts in switch s1 spark, I did a simple
>   test and found that there are no sparks even with high amperage. I am
>   unable to explain why this is so?

Every switching contact is bypassed by a short circuit hence the contacts can neither take much current nor spark.

I recommend you use a sim tool and see this for yourself - model the contacts as 1 milli-ohm resistances and get a feel for what will happen: -

[image]

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I will try the sim and hopefully see the light.